# SSAS cube browsing gives different results from database query

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssas, mdx, cube

I'm executing the following query in my database engine containing my dimension tables and fact table, I'm grouping by dates the number of accesses of one ID

```
SELECT d.Date bp, count(NumberOfAccess)
from dbo.Fact fb inner join DimDates d on fb.Dates=d.Dates
where WebService='wsNAPSBan' and ID='200'
group by d.Date
order by bp desc
```

and it gives me the following results:

[image]

However when I browse the cube it gives me different results:

[image]

Any idea what the problem might be?

Comment: I found the what the problem was, in SSAS I should have picked count instead of sum

Comment: You can answer your question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what the problem was, in ssas I used sum instead of count